# Change Function + ajax cant send value parameter from select box to django views (to make a dependent dropdown)

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax

So i have 2 select box , first select box has a list of schema that the database has (i use oracle in DBEAVER) 
so the directory is like

```
Oracle - databasename
|Schema
  |A
  |B
  |C
  |D
  |E
    |Tables
       |POLLS_TableAll
       |DJANGO_ADMINUSER
       |etc
    |Views
    |Sequence
    |Types
    |etc
  |F
  |G
```

polls_tableall has 2 attribute , table_id and table_name that we insert the data manually depends on list of schema and we put the table id increment

P.S: table_name is schema ( my friends name it table, sry for it)

```
tableid     table_name
1           A
2           B
3           C
4           D
5           E
6           F
7           G
8           H
```

so what i want is to make a dependent select box (dropdown list)

the first dropdown has a list of table_name(which i already finish it)
when i choose for example 'E' the second dropdown will show the POLLS_TableAll , Django_Adminuser , etc

models.py

```
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django import forms

class TableAll(models.Model):
    table_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

views.py

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render, redirect
from django.template import loader
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import TableAll

#for first select box
def list_all_table(request):    
  obj = TableAll.objects.all()
  context = {
       'obj' : obj
  }
  return render(request,'define_segment.html',context)

# for second select box
def load_data(request):
    table_name = request.GET.get('table_name')
    dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('IP', 'PORT', sid='SID')
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r' ', password=' ', dsn=dsn_tns)
    c = conn.cursor()
    obj2 = c.execute ("SELECT table_name FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE owner = '"+table_name+"'")
    context = {
       'obj2' : obj2
    }
    return render(request,data_list.html,context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
            path('', views.login_view, name='login'),
            path('home/', views.index_view, name='indexing'),
            path('profile/', views.profile_view, name='profile'),
            path('chatroom/', views.chatroom, name='chat_room'),
            path('lockscreen/', views.lockscreen, name='lock_screen'),
            path('newsegment/', views.createsegment, name='newsegment'),
            path('definesegment/', views.list_all_table, name='definesegment'),
            path('manageuser/', views.manageuser, name='manageuser'),  
            path('approvallist/', views.approvallist, name='approvallist'),   
            path('approvalhistory/', views.approvalhistory, name='approvalhistory'),    
            path('ajax/load-data',views.load_data,name='load-data'),
        ]
```

define_segment.html

```
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<script>
       $(document).ready(function()
       {
          $('#tableselect').change(function() {
          var url = "{% static url 'load-data' %}";
          var table_name = $(this).val();
          $.ajax({
            url : url,
            data : {
              'table_name' = table_name
            },
            success : function(data){
               $('#dataselect').html(data);
            }
           });
         });
       });
</script>
 ...
<form class="form-horizontal  style-form" action="#">
       <div class="form-group">
             <label class="control-label col-md-3">Database Name</label>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
                              <div class="btn-group">
                                  <select id="tableselect" style="width:425px;background-color:white;height:30px;font-color:red;text-align-last:center;">              
                                    <!-- <li><a href="#"></a></li> -->
                                       {% for table_name in obj %}
                                        <option value="{{table_name.table_name}}">{{ table_name.table_name }}
                                      {% endfor %}                          
                                    <!-- <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li> -->
                                    </option>
                                </select>                    
                           </div>
                      </div>
                </div>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="control-label col-md-3">Table Name</label>
                       <div class="col-md-4">
                           <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
                               <div class="btn-group">
                                    <select id ="dataselect" style="width:425px;background-color:white;height:30px;font-color:red;text-align-last:center;">              


                                    </select>                    
                             </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
        </form>

...
{% endblock %}
```

0001_initial.py

```
from django.db import migrations, models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import django.db.models.deletion

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

   initial = True

   dependencies = [
   ]

   role = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   role.contribute_to_class(User,'role')    

   operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
           name='TableAll',
           fields=[                
               ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
               ('table_name', models.CharField(max_length=250)),                
           ],
       ),
    ]
```

data_list.html #toload the option value if ajax success

```
{% for data in obj %}
     <option value="{{ data.table_name }}">{{ data.table_name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

is there anything i wrong? when i select the choice, it wont send any parameter it seems like a HTML without a view function ..

maybe someone can fix the code here , or what am i missing, thankyou

Comment: Please use correct formatting / indentation

Comment: omg sry , w8 i edit it

Answer (score 0):

You should write your Ajax below the form. So take the separate block in base.html or any html file ( where you have declared jQuery) below the decoration of jQuery.

In base.html or .html file in which you have declared your jQuery.

```
{% block extrajs %}
{% endblock  %}
```

then in your this html file after the {% endblock %}

```
{% block extrajs %}

    <script>
           $(document).ready(function()
           {
              $('#tableselect').change(function() {
              var url = "{% static url 'load-data' %}";
              var table_name = $(this).val();
              $.ajax({
                url : url,
                data : {
                  'table_name' = table_name
                },
                success : function(data){
                   $('#dataselect').html(data);
                }
               });
             });
           });
    </script>
    {% endblock  %}
```

Comment: sry just get back from work, hmm it didnt work , or maybe the jquery is wrong or maybe the select option is wrong hm, do i need to give onchange = this.form.submit() in the select element

Comment: have you tried as I wrote in the answer? have you put `{ % extrajs   %}`  below your main jquery in base.html?